# How to Display a Resource From a Custom Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have a custom CloudFormation resource that creates an S3 bucket if it doesn't exist. Here is the code:

```
  S3CustomResource:
Type: Custom::S3CustomResource
Properties:
  ServiceToken: !GetAtt AWSLambdaFunction.Arn
  the_bucket: !Ref S3BucketName

  AWSLambdaFunction:
 Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
 Properties:
   Description: "Work with S3 Buckets!"
   FunctionName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::Region}-lambda'
   Handler: index.handler
   Role: !GetAtt AWSLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
   Timeout: 360
   Runtime: python3.6
   Code:
     ZipFile: |
      import boto3
      import cfnresponse
      def handler(event, context):
          # Init ...
          the_event = event['RequestType']
          print("The event is: ", str(the_event))
          response_data = {}
          s_3 = boto3.client('s3')
          # Retrieve parameters
          the_bucket = event['ResourceProperties']['the_bucket']
          try:
              if the_event in ('Create', 'Update'):
                  print("Requested to create S3 bucket: ", str(the_bucket))
                  for bucket_name in the_bucket:
                      print("Creating: ", str(bucket_name))
                      s_3.create_bucket(Bucket=the_bucket)
              elif the_event == 'Delete':
                  print("Whoopsie, this bucket has some seriuos information in it - let's not delete it")
              # Everything OK... send the signal back
              print("Execution succesfull!")
              cfnresponse.send(event,
                               context,
                               cfnresponse.SUCCESS,
                               response_data)
          except Exception as e:
              print("Execution failed...")
              print(str(e))
              response_data['Data'] = str(e)
              cfnresponse.send(event,
                               context,
                               cfnresponse.FAILED,
                               response_data)
```

I would like to reference the ARN of this bucket in my other CloudFormation resources. The S3CustomResource resource only shows the PhysicalID of the CloudWatch Log name. How can I get CloudFormation to show the bucket ARN as a PhysicalID in the Resource tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bucket ARNs have **fixed format**, so you just use that in your code (assuming `aws` partition):

```
bucket_arn = "arn:aws:s3:::" + bucket_name
```

and you return them in `response_data`. Below is fully **working**, amended code that can create **multiple buckets** using custom resource and returns their ARN to cloudformation for future use. The code has a lot of room for improvement, e.g. return arns of buckets if they exist, check if buckets were correctly created and more. Thus its not ideal code, but it works and shows the key elements:

- passing lists to custom resource
- returning lists of arns to CFN
- accessing the list in CFN

```
Parameters:

  S3BucketName:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList  
    Default: test-bucket-312ddfff,test-bucket3333-312ddfff

Resources:

  S3CustomResource:
    Type: Custom::S3CustomResource
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt AWSLambdaFunction.Arn
      the_bucket: !Ref S3BucketName

  AWSLambdaFunction:
     Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
     Properties:
       Description: "Work with S3 Buckets!"
       FunctionName: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-${AWS::Region}-lambda'
       Handler: index.handler
       Role: !GetAtt AWSLambdaExecutionRole.Arn
       Timeout: 360
       Runtime: python3.6
       Code:
         ZipFile: |
          import boto3
          import cfnresponse

          s_3 = boto3.client('s3')
          s3_waiter = s_3.get_waiter('bucket_exists')

          def handler(event, context):
              # Init ...
              
              print(event)

              the_event = event['RequestType']
              print("The event is: ", str(the_event))
              
              response_data = {}              

              # Retrieve parameters
              the_bucket = event['ResourceProperties']['the_bucket']
              
              print("the_bucket", the_bucket)
              
              bucket_arns = []

              try:
                  if the_event in ('Create', 'Update'):

                      print("Requested to create S3 bucket: ", 
                             str(the_bucket))

                      for bucket_name in the_bucket:
                      
                          print("Creating: ", str(bucket_name))
                          
                          s_3.create_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
                          
                          s3_waiter.wait(Bucket=bucket_name)
                          
                          bucket_arn = "arn:aws:s3:::" + bucket_name
                          
                          bucket_arns.append(bucket_arn)

                  elif the_event == 'Delete':
                      print("Whoopsie, this bucket has some"
                            "seriuos information in it "
                            "- let's not delete it")
                      cfnresponse.send(event, context,
                                       cfnresponse.SUCCESS,
                                       response_data)
                      return

                  # Everything OKindex... send the signal back

                  print("Execution successful!")
                  
                  response_data['arns'] = ','.join(bucket_arns)

                  cfnresponse.send(event,
                                   context,
                                   cfnresponse.SUCCESS,
                                   response_data)

              except Exception as e:

                  print("Execution failed...")
                  print(str(e))
                  
                  response_data['Data'] = str(e)

                  cfnresponse.send(event,
                                   context,
                                   cfnresponse.FAILED,
                                   response_data)
               
               
  AWSLambdaExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'               
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal: {'Service': ['lambda.amazonaws.com']}
            Action: ['sts:AssumeRole']
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess
      Path: '/'
      
      
Outputs:

  BucketArns:
    Value: !GetAtt S3CustomResource.arns
```

Comment: This solution gives me the output of the ARN not the PhysicalID in the resource field. Can outputs be referenced in the same template file for other resources?

Comment: One more thing, the output returned me this result
`BucketArns arn:aws:s3:::b,arn:aws:s3:::b,arn:aws:s3:::d,arn:aws:s3:::n,arn:aws:s3:::a,arn:aws:s3:::x,arn:aws:s3:::u,arn:aws:s3:::i,arn:aws:s3:::1,arn:aws:s3:::0` Can you help me understand why it duplicated the first part of the arn and added the first character (and so on) of the bucket name?

Comment: @gumluvinisgoodluvin I don't know what did you change in the code. It works as expected as I tested it.

Comment: The code work flawlessly, but I would like to use only 1 bucket for this (not multiple comma separated). Any advice what I can change?

Comment: @gumluvinisgoodluvin I does this because you are creating buckets in the loop `for bucket_name in the_bucket`. Thus I fixed the code to work with the loop. If you pass only a single string as `the_bucket`, you will iterate over individual characters, thus creating a bucket for each character.

Comment: Awesome, that did the job! So just to summarize, we're not able reference the S3 bucket ARN in the Resource tab, only in the Outputs? Asking this because I would like to automate the whole stack creation in one CloudFormation template file.

Comment: @gumluvinisgoodluvin You can reference it in `Resources` using `!GetAtt S3CustomResource.arns`. I just put it in my code in `Outputs`, as I do not use any other resources in my example code.

Comment: Right right. Thank you for the help, case closed.

Comment: @gumluvinisgoodluvin No problem. Glad my answer was helpful:-)